# AES CTR Encryption in Java under different Android Version

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I was trying to encode a string using Cipher with "AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING" but I got different encrypted string (different in the length of the string as well) when the same coding is used in a physical android phone (android 4.4 API 19) and virtual android device (Nexus 5X API 26) under the same keygen. The virtual android device could generate string with 32bytes but the physical one couldn't (which has the same length of the string to be encoded).

Would it be the problem of cipher which is not supported for old version android?

Below is the testing coding used:

```
    byte[] Input = "Testing123".getBytes();
    byte[] encoded_key = Base64.decode("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQABCDEFGHI", Base64.DEFAULT);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encoded_key, 0, encoded_key.length, "AES");
    byte[] iv = new byte[128 / 8];
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    String Output = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(Input), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Under old android, output = "nG3YdbntTrRBxQ=="
while under new android, output = "nG3YdbntTrRBxQd2fUg1ow=="

Thanks~

Finally, i found out this is because old android doesnt support with padding encryption.

Comment: Are you using the same 'block-size'?

Comment: How to set the block size? The string to be encoded are the same but not in 32 byte. It seems that padding is not working in some android version...

Comment: So under the old physical android, the output byte is the same length of the input byte but its not enough as i will treat it as base 64 to convert it as string

Comment: @n247s Block size of AES is fixed at 128 bits.

Comment: Post your code.  "Couldn't" is a very poor description of the problem.

Comment: As you discovered, Android ignored the padding specification for CTR mode until some time between API 20-26 inclusive. One interoperability problem is that the Oracle Java providers also ignore the padding, but the current Bouncycastle provider honors the padding. In my opinion ignoring the padding is a bug.